# Missing certain data in API

Tags: data-request, api, openfda, uses-of-open-data

We are using the below API to fetch data based on dates:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=MyAPIKey&search=date_received:[20230702+TO+20230704]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CCK%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=MyAPIKey&search=date_received:%5B20230702+TO+20230704%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CCK%22&limit=1000)

but the above API does not provide all the data as it is missing below report numbers based on different dates and all these report numbers are for older data means it should be present using the above API call.

2016493-2023-190093,
2518435-2023-00011,
2518435-2023-00014,
2518435-2023-00020,
2518435-2023-00021,
2518435-2023-00022,
3014663932-2023-00005,
3014663932-2023-00006,
3014663932-2023-00010,
3014663932-2023-00011,
3005520039-2023-00001

however the above report numbers are present when we search on below:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Shailendra Jetpuria

Answer (score 0):

openFDA updates the device event endpoint roughly quarterly, so the early July records are not in the current dataset. We are due for an update soon though, so that data should be available in the very near future.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead

Answer (score 0):

Device Event dataset updates weekly. This issue should now be fixed. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

We are still not able to get the july month data for example if you search this report number 2016493-2023-190093 in https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm you will get two results for july month, now try the below API URL within date range of june to july 23 and you see that this report number is not there in the API response:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=T1Hc46PBzj4XxShHdLhmdfilfr9Xpsd1DmpZo0or&search=date_received:[20230630+TO+20230731]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CCK%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=T1Hc46PBzj4XxShHdLhmdfilfr9Xpsd1DmpZo0or&search=date_received:%5B20230630+TO+20230731%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CCK%22&limit=1000)

Similarly the other report numbers below for older months have been missing from the API results:

2518435-2023-00011, 2518435-2023-00014, 2518435-2023-00020, 2518435-2023-00021, 2518435-2023-00022, 3014663932-2023-00005, 3014663932-2023-00006, 3014663932-2023-00010, 3014663932-2023-00011, 3005520039-2023-00001

Kindly help on this as this is quite urgent.

Thanks,
Shailendra Jetpuria

Comment: Hi @Violet Wren any update on missing records?